# How to deal with POST requests with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

It is my first time to write a POST-request function, and I could not work this function using "Axios".
Here are HTML and JavaScript files.
[image]

HTML (This is where you can input values to each column ("English" and "Japanese") and save them to MongoDB when you click a "Save Them" button.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Your Words!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Your New Words!</h1>
    <div class="transtable">
        <table class="table" id="ENJP" border="1">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">English</th>
              <th scope="col">Japanese</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ><input type="text" name="English"/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Japanese"/>
                </td>
                <td><input class="closeBtn" type="button" value="X" onclick="DelRow(event)"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="opt_1">
        <input type="button" value="Add a Row" onclick="AddRow()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Save Them" onclick="SaveToDB()"/>
      </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsfile [refer to *SaveToDB* which is what I would ask about]

```
// Send requests to a server to receive MongoDB data
let table = document.getElementById("ENJP");

const AddRow = () => {
    //Add a new row
    let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    //Make cells and insert a row with them
    let cel_EN = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let cel_JP = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let cel_DeleteButton = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let rowContentEN = '<input type="text" name="English"/>';
    let rowContentJP = '<input type="text" name="Japanese"/>';
    let rowDeleteButton = '<input class="closeBtn" type="button" value="X" onclick="DelRow(event)"/>';
    cel_EN.innerHTML = rowContentEN;
    cel_JP.innerHTML = rowContentJP;
    cel_DeleteButton.innerHTML = rowDeleteButton;
}

// Delete a row you choose to click X button
const DelRow = (event) =>{
   event.target.closest('tr').remove();
}

const SaveToDB = () => {
// An array to have each row's values at the last phase
    let data = [];
    let tbl_tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    let tdData = ""
 //Process each row
    tbl_tr.forEach(function(tr){
         console.log(tr.innerText)
     //Get <td> tags and skip the first row
        let cells = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
        if (cells.length!=0){
         // This variable has data of rows
         let d = []
         cells.forEach(function(td){
            if(td.innerHTML.indexOf('input') !== -1) {
                tdData = td.querySelector('input').value;
                d.push(tdData);
            }
            else if(td.textContent !== ""){
                tdData = td.innerText;
                d.push(tdData);
            }
            else{
                d.push("NoData");
            }
         });
         data.push(d);
         

         let outcomeData = axios.post("/word/addwords", data);
         console.log(outcomeData);       
        }
    });
}
```

JS file (back end)

```
// expressとmongoose使用宣言
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// DBをwordsに代入
const words = require('./models/words');
// expressのインスタンス作成
const app = express();
// publicフォルダ内を使用する処理。
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
const port = 3000;
console.log("hello!!");


mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv:// (I omitted this part)    /testdb"
).then(()=>console.log("Connecting"))
app.get('/', (req,res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

// DBに登録用関数 ここにAdd画面からのリストを受け取る。
function registerData(){
    let bkData = new words({
        english: "Mary Barton",
        japanese: "Elizabeth Gaskell"
    })
    bkData.save()
}
function add_NewWords(){
  console.log("DID IT!")
}

// ローカルホストに/book追加で入力すると作動する。
app.get("/word", async (req,res) => {
    // 全部取得
    try {
        // 全データをbksで取得して、resに乗せて引き渡し。
        const bks = await words.find({});
        res.status(200).json(bks);
        console.log(bks)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
  });

//データ追加
app.post("/word/addwords", async(req, res)=>{
  try {
    let bkData = new words({
      english: req[0],
      japanese: req[1]
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("Save it");
  
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

My trouble is that values of HTML's input tags cannot be sent to MongoDB.

Comment: axios.post is an async function, so you'll need to use either .then or async / await ideally.

Comment: can you also share what error you're seeing server side

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.  The errors I got are here (I will attach a picture of the browser in later comment).  What I input in the broewer was sent to the Back end, but the Back end (app.js) did not register them into Mongo DB.　I mean that the app.js went to a "catch" course, which occurs when the program has any errors.  app.post("/word/addwords", async(req, res)=>{
  try {
    let bkData = new words({
      english: req.data[0],
      japanese: req.data[1]
      
    })
    console.log(req.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("I cannot register words");
  }

  
})

Comment: `req[0]` — What gave you the idea to write that? [Try this search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=express+post+request).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick comment. I will try your advice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I mean "req[0]" for a value of the column "English" , which I thought could receive it in the Back end.  But, my code still goes to the error course in the Back end (app.js)  and my MongoDB is not be able to get values from the front end (script.js) . Could you tell me how to send data in detail?  Here are my codes;  ```let toDB = {english: data[0][0], japanese: data[0][1]};
        //  console.log(toDB);

         const henji = axios.post("/word/addwords", toDB)
         .then(()=>{console.log("success")})
              ```  (script.js)

Comment: app.js (Back end) ```app.post("/word/addwords", async(req, res)=>{
  try {
    // Here I want to put data from the front end.
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("I cannot register words");
  }
})```

Comment: Thanks to your kind support, I am almost there to solve my problem;  now, I could not add new values from the front end (script.js) to the DB through the Back end (app.js)

Comment: ```app.post("/word/addwords", async(req, res)=>{
  try {
    
    console.log("You success if this message shows on Terminal!")
    let enWord = req.body.English
    let jpWord = req.body.Japanese
    let added_word = new words({
      English: req.body.English,
      Japanese: req.body.Japanese
    })
    added_word.save();

    //enWord and jpWord have their values, but added_word only has {id: xxxx}.
    console.log(enWord);
    console.log(jpWord);
    console.log(added_word);
    
    
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("I cannot register words");
  }
})```

Answer (score 0):

`axios.post` is an async operation, so you need to either `await` it or use `.then`.

### Promises

You need to pass a callback function to `.then()` - the first param of `then` is a resolved value, which in this case, will be a Response object.

See axios.post docs for more information.

https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

```
axios.post("/word/addwords", data).then((outcomeData) => { console.log(outcomeData) })
```

### Async / Await

Async / Await is syntax sugar around Promises; so your function that is performing an await needs to become async.

Refer to the documentation on Async / Await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

See the below example with your code.

```
tbl_tr.forEach(async function(tr) {
  // ...

  let outcomeData = await axios.post("/word/addwords", data);
  console.log(outcomeData);       
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I am very glad to add it to my options in future developments!